# Fastly - error page detect and serve from specific server

Tags: fastly

We have two servers running with Fastly as the CDN and filtering which types of content get served by which build. In the Fastly code base, we have a `.tl` file and a `.vcl` file that contains all logic that defines which routes point to which server.

As for the code base for both servers, are all developed in Laravel.

Problem:

Is there a way to build a rule or logic of some kind that fastly forces error status to a specific server? If so, what would it look like?

By the way: my knowledge on Fastly is very limited, but I have advanced knowledge in JavaScript, PHP, regex.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a working example, using [Fastly's Fiddle tool](https://developer.fastly.com/learning/tools/fiddle/), based on my understanding of what you were trying to achieve:

https://fiddle.fastly.dev/fiddle/dd727e98

Here are some other resources available that might assist you:

- [VCL Examples](https://developer.fastly.com/solutions/examples/vcl/) (here's one that [redirects URLs at the edge](https://developer.fastly.com/solutions/examples/redirect-old-urls-at-the-edge)).
- [VCL Reference](https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/)

If you have any further questions then I'd recommend reaching out to support@fastly.com who will be happy to help.

All the best.